# Realm query to exclude results from relations

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have

```
class Person: Object {
    let friends = List<Person>()
    let family = List<Person>()
}
```

I have `person` instance, which includes links to some other persons in `person.friends` list.
And I want to query all other `Person` objects, not including `person.friends` and `person`.

I can make two `for in` loops to check if the query doesn't contain persons from the list, but it seems like not the best way to do that.

P.S. In CoreData I did it with predicate:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF != %@ AND NOT SELF IN %@",person, person.friends),
```

But Realm gives me an error:

> Predicate expressions must compare a keypath and another keypath or a
>   constant value

.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this predicate is currently unsupported in Realm -- you can follow https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1328 for updates.